# Cannot make transparent background when saving canvas to gif

Tags: javascript, canvas, gif

I'm using the very handy javascript canvas to gif script from here: https://github.com/antimatter15/jsgif

But I can't seem to get transparent backgrounds to work. It just comes out black.

HTML:

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="960" height="540" />
```

Javascript:

```
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"); // get canvas
const context = canvas.getContext('2d') //get context


ctx.fillStyle = "#000000"; // set bg color to black
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height) // fill the background


var encoder =  new window.GIFEncoder()
encoder.setRepeat(0);

encoder.setQuality(200)
encoder.setTransparent(0x000000) // set black to be transparent
        
encoder.start();
       
encoder.setDelay(delay);
encoder.addFrame(ctx);

encoder.finish();
encoder.download("download.gif");
```

But the result is just a gif with black background rather than transparent. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After digging through the sourcecode of `GIFEncoder.js` I realized, it's not your fault - there's simply a little bug.

As soon as you determine a transparent color using the GIFEncoder's `.setTransparent()` method, it internally invokes the function `findClosest`, which searches through the actual colour palette and tries to find a near match between the stored colors and the transparent color you would like to have.

If a match is found it looks up another table - `usedEntry` - to find out if the color is actually used in your image - and there's the culprit. To get the index into the table it does:

```
var index = i / 3;
```

The outer loop though does not get incremented in multiples of 3, so the result of this division is always a floating point number thus there is no valid index.

If you replace the above with:

```
var index = (i + 1) / 3;
```

it will work.

## Edit

Obviously this ain't the only bug with the GIFEncoder library. GIF files can have a shared global color palette and optionally local color palettes for subsequent frames - which this library takes use of. To do this it analyzes the pixel data for each frame and writes the used color indexes - like above - into the `usedEntry` array. Unfortunately it does not get reset for a new analysis stage.

If you add

`usedEntry = [];`

at the begining of the `analyzePixels()` function it will keep the transparency for animations.

Comment: Wow thanks so much for diving so deep into this! This *almost* works. it goes correctly transparent for the first frame, but then reverts back to being the solid colour for all the other frames. Any ideas?

Comment: actually, sometimes it's the first few frames that have transparency, and then it goes back to the bg being solid

Comment: I edited my answer Jonathan.

Comment: Hey - this didn't work, but adding usedEntry = []; at the start of the addFrame function + your var index = (i + 1) / 3; trick worked. if you update your answer to include I'll accept it to make it easier for anyone else who comes along. THANKS SO MUCH!

Comment: Glad I could help Jonathan! By the way - maybe you put it at the wrong spot. The `usedEntry` array is solely used within the `analyzePixels()` function - so if it's reset at the very beginning of this function everything's okay. I double checked that and it's working.

Comment: i put it there to start with and it didn't work, not sure why. i'll try it again, but it's working now

it also helped with another bug which is that the export works the first time, and then would fail subsequent times. this seems to keep it all working for multiple exports.